# How to color @ (at symbol) in Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs, special-characters, keyword, font-face

I can color keywords in emacs using the following lisp code in .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords nil
           '(("\\<\\(bla[a-zA-Z1-9_]*\\)" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

This code color all keywords that start with "bla". Example: blaTest123_test

However when I try to add @ (the 'at' symbol) instead of "bla", it doesn't seem to work. I don't think @ is a special character for regular expressions.

Do you know how I can get emacs to highlight keywords starting with the @ symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `\<` in your regexp, which

> matches the empty string, but only at the beginning of a word. `\<' matches at the beginning of the buffer (or string) only if a word-constituent character follows.

and `@` is not a word-constituent character.

See: <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Regexp Backslash")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

This unrestricted pattern will colour any `@`:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("@" 0 font-lock-warning-face t)))
```

And this will do something like what you want, by requiring either BOL or some white space immediately beforehand.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("\\(?:^\\|\\s-\\)\\(@[a-zA-Z1-9_]*\\)" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))
```

Comment: btw, I just noticed that you specified `[1-9]` rather than `[0-9]`. I imagine you want to allow zeros as well?

Comment: Also, a better approach for this particular case would be to add a syntax-table entry for that particular symbol.  Make it "punctuation" and font-lock will automatically set the punctuation font-face on the symbol.